# How to increase the accuracy of a multivariate LSTM network?

Tags: python, forecasting, accuracy, lstm, pandas

I am using a pollution dataset with values for pm2.5, pm10 and pm1 as features and I am predicting the values for the pm2.5. I built an LSTM network but the predicted values are quite from the real values.

```
win_length=2 
batch_size=32  
num_features=3

train_generator=TimeseriesGenerator(x_train,y_train,length=win_length,sampling_rate=1,batch_size=batch_size)
test_generator=TimeseriesGenerator(x_test,y_test,length=win_length,sampling_rate=1,batch_size=batch_size)
```

This is the model:

```
model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(200,input_shape=(win_length,num_features),return_sequences=True)) #take every obs into account

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.5))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128,return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.5)) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,return_sequences=False)) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

I am also using early stopping to prevent overfitting:

```
early_stopping=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=2,mode='min')
model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])
history=model.fit(train_generator,epochs=50,validation_data=test_generator,shuffle=False,callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

And here is the prediction plot versus the real values:
[image]

I am using 20% of data as test data.
The notebook can be found here: https://github.com/creativitylab/dataset/blob/main/pollution%20data.ipynb

What could I try to change, to improve the prediction values?